# How to provide updates to the app deployed as a VM solution on Google Cloud Marketplace?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I wish to offer my application as a [VM solution](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm) on Google Cloud Marketplace. However I haven't figured out how to provide updates to my application. As far I as I know, I need to deprecate the existing image and update it with a new one. I am not sure how existing customers will get the updated application. Could somebody please help me understand this ?

Comment: Hi there. For `planning to deploy a VM solution on Google Cloud Marketplace` you mean that you will offer your application in the Marketplace or that you plan to install an application from the marketplace and you want to know how to get updates?

Comment: I want to offer my application as vm solution on the marketplace and would like to know how do I push updates to my application once the customer has deployed it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs#updating_a_software_package) the customer is unable to update software that they have already deployed.

In order to update their existing deployment of a software package, they must redeploy the software package from Cloud Marketplace.

Comment: Isn't that doc referring to updates managed by google as opposed to updates managed by the solution provider?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new version for your solution in the marketplace UI and then get that approved and released by Google. Once that's released, customers can update to the new version by updating the deployment yaml under the "Applications" section in GKE with the new application version.